# How to customize CommitCharacters set for any language?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In Visual Studio Code by default, in JavaScript when you type a part of an item in suggestion list and type one of Commit Characters set {**"."**,  **";"**,  **"("**,  etc...}, suggestion will accepted and followed by commit character.

Can I edit this character set, adding or removing items in JavaScript and other languages?

I searched and didn't find any settings to customize this set